# Align items by text in a QListWidget (Icon mode)

Tags: c++, qt

While creating a "gallery-like" widget (using `QListWidget` and adding QIcons) I am unable to align the items when the source images have different aspect ratio.

The `QListWidget` object is initialized as follows:

```
mListWidget->setViewMode    (QListWidget::IconMode  );
mListWidget->setResizeMode  (QListWidget::Adjust    );
mListWidget->setIconSize    (QSize(100,100         ));
mListWidget->setAcceptDrops (true                   );
mListWidget->setDragEnabled (false                  );
```

And then each new icon is added:

```
QListWidgetItem* item = new QListWidgetItem(QIcon(QPixmap(path)), path.split("/").last());
mListWidget->addItem(item);
```

The result is the following:

[image]

As you can see, the labels of the different elements are not aligned, which looks ugly. Is there a way of fixing this (e.g. by setting the height of the list elements but not the width)?

Answer (score 1):

Then add the following code:

```
item->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter|Qt::AlignBottom);
item->setSizeHint(QSize(100, 120));
```

Comment: Nope, it doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the scaled method and set size & ignore the aspect ration as shown in the below code.

```
QImageReader imageReader("Image Path");
imageReader.setDecideFormatFromContent(true);
QImage styleIcon = imageReader.read();
QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(styleIcon);
QPixmap newPixmap = pixmap.scaled(QSize(80, 80), Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio);
QListWidgetItem* item = new QListWidgetItem(newPixmap, "");
```